# Clone external Github repository with github actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions

How can I clone an external repository within the same organization with github Actions. However I get the repository not found error.

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with: 
    repository: Test-App/argocd-configuration.git
    ref: deploy-api
    ssh-key: ${{ secrets.ORG_SSH_REPO_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

The above exits with `fatal respotiory`

We clone the repo only with SSH keys and the same key is used to clone all the repositories.

How can i clone an external repository?

Comment: Any solution on this? I'm not able to clone with .github folder

Answer (score 1):

as per docu:

```
- name: Checkout private tools
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    repository: your-test-org/your-private-repo-in-org 
    ref: deploy-api #your branch/tag or commit sha name
    token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }} # `GH_PAT` is a secret that contains your PAT
```

PAT for external repos is not the GITHUB_TOKEN, it is a personal access token as per https://gh.r-lib.org/articles/managing-personal-access-tokens.html

Don't add the .git to the repo name and make sure the GH_PAT has SSO access to that organization as well!

Hope that helps :)